# PDO: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Feeling a little stupid to ask such a question, but this code block is driving me crazy.

```
function __construct() {
    $db = new db();
    $this->db = $db->pdo;
}

function getEmployeeDetails() {
    $eid = $this->db->quote($this->eid);
    try {
        $sql = $this->db->query("
            SELECT email, cnumber
            FROM employees
            WHERE EID = $eid
        ");
        $r = $sql->fetch();
        $this->email = $r[0];
        $this->cnumber = $r[1];
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new Exception("failed");
    }
}
```

It doesn't throw an exception but fails inside the try block - "Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object".

1. var_dump of the statement object returns 'false'. Why?
2. I've tried running the query independently, inside MySql. It returns 1 row.

Comment: Are you defining those functions inside a class?

Comment: yup. they're defined inside a class

Comment: That error message means that the variable (in this case `$sql`) is not an object. In other words, the `$this->db->query()` method does not return a result; it probably returns `null` or `false`, or something like that.

Comment: The weird thing is that if I run the query independently, it returns 1 row.

Comment: Why on Earth would you do that with an exception?!

Comment: "What's wrong with this block of code?" is an offtopic question to ask.

Comment: Should I rephrase it?

Comment: Made an edit to the title of the question. To make it more searchable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to tell whether you have done this, but PDO doesn't throw exceptions by default, except on connection failures. You have to specifically add this:

```
$this->db = $db->pdo;
$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Without this, errors that occur during the query will cause `->query()` to return `false` and that's obviously not an object that will have the `->fetch()` method. You can also specify this attribute as part of the constructor call.

Also, you could use prepared statements instead of using `->quote()`:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT email, cnumber
    FROM employees
    WHERE EID = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($this->eid));
$r = $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: aha! the first part of your answer helped me identify the problem. i'll accept your answer shortly. thanks :)

Comment: regarding the second part of your answer: is it a good practice to use prepared statements even though i'm running only one query? Will it not be significantly slower?

Comment: @om_deshpande It's a good practice because you can more safely focus on just the query instead of escaping your variables; speed, although not an issue here, should not be your number one priority :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Why the constant foreboding appearances?

Comment: Speaking of this particular case - because the code in question *is* foreboding itself. Also you can attend to the above link yourself and read a very simple explanation why your approach of setting error mode considered unreliable.

Comment: Speaking of foreboding appearances in general - it is because SO is all about *imaginary programming*. People giving out advises on the matters they never had real experience with. All the knowledge here is *virtual*, it is just roaming from one answer to another, without any reality check. This is where my foreboding from in general.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You mean the part where it says: (`ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`) ... is the only reliable way to handle PDO errors.?

Comment: Nope, it is on "It is essential to set ERRMODE_EXCEPTION as a connection option as it will let PDO throw exceptions on **connection errors.**"

Comment: @YourCommonSense Are you saying that PDO does not throw an exception on connection errors if you omit the error mode attribute from the constructor?

Comment: But how it can? If you set it only  **after** connect? It does, though, in some installations where errmode is set to exception already by default (though I don't know yet to tell such an installation and where it is being set). But in such a case you don't have to bother with setting it manually at all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) seems to suggest otherwise: "PDO::__construct() throws a PDOException if the attempt to connect to the requested database fails."

Comment: This is what I call "virtual knowledge", exactly :) "[Some resource] I read says...". While my point were **real experience**. That's two different matters, you know.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Not just some resource, it's the official documentation; furthermore, it matches my experience with it. If you think otherwise, feel free to pick it up with the PHP team instead.

Comment: There are many rubbish in the official documentation - don't you know? It's hard to pick it up with the PHP team though, as nobody actually cares.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the behavior right now with versions I have at hand. Though I am sure I had that experience already, I have to withdraw my claim at the moment. My apologies. Got to investigate it some more.

Comment: Also @YourCommonSense feel free to ping me or one of the others here or in the php chat if the documentation needs works somewhere or feel free to send a [patch yourself](https://edit.php.net/?project=PHP&perm=en/pdo.construct.php) and when the patch is correct we will be more than happy to commit it.

Comment: Well, it seems it was my fault of the very same kind I was ranting about, heh.

Comment: @PeeHaa I am not too good with reading PHP-src, but [this line](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c#L106) hints me that Jack is right and I am wrong. Thanks for the invitation though. I had another correction pending, [which I hopefully submitted right now](https://edit.php.net/?perm=/en/mysqli.quickstart.php&project=PHP). Some grammar check most likely required.